# Log4j not creating log file, just consoles

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Trying to using Log4j to create a logger file, but with the properties below i can't doing this.

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, toFile, toConsole;

log4j.appender.toFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.toFile.File=${user.home}/.log/logger.log
log4j.appender.toFile.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.toFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.toFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#Console
log4j.appender.toConsole=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.toConsole.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.toConsole.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss} %5p [%t] - %c.%M - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// import following :

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
```

//and
need to add following method in the main file to make the log4j property file readable

```
static {


 PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
}
```